# AMPScript - LookupOrderedRows returns 0 rows

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, error

I am trying to retrieve all my product rows that match the last region of my user.

So I begin to set my user's last region:

```
set @LAST_STAY_REGION = AttributeValue("LAST_STAY_REGION")
```

If I print this variable using `%%=v(@LAST_STAY_REGION)=%%` the ID of the region is returned just fine.

Then I retrieve data of my product table using the following code:

```
set @SAME_REGION = Lookuporderedrows("PRODUCTS","2","SORT_ORDER_FR DESC","REGION_ID","%%=v(@LAST_STAY_REGION)=%%")
```

However when I count the number of rows returned with count rows function, the results is 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, that you use the [V-function](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/v/#v) which is for outputting variable values. If you like to use a variable as function parameter just use the variable name (in your case `@LAST_STAY_REGION`) instead:

```
set @SAME_REGION = Lookuporderedrows("PRODUCTS", "2", "SORT_ORDER_FR DESC", "REGION_ID", @LAST_STAY_REGION)
```